# Dataflow unable to write data to BigQuery due to permission errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-3.5, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Good Morning All,

I am sure this is a simple question, but I am very new to both Google Cloud and to Python 3, so please be gentle.

I am looking to extract data from SQL Server using pyodbc, which was simple enough.  I now want to publish that information to a PubSub topic, which is where I am facing some problems.

For some background, this will be the second part of a 4 part process. Ultimately the desired workflow will look like this:

SQL Server --> Google Cloud PubSub --> Dataflow --> Big Query

I leveraged the Google Documentation code publisher.py obtained via

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git
```

Which originally looked like this:

```
def publish_messages(project_id, topic_name):
    """Publishes multiple messages to a Pub/Sub topic."""
    # [START pubsub_quickstart_publisher]
    # [START pubsub_publish]
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    # TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
    # TODO topic_name = "Your Pub/Sub topic name"

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    # The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
    # in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}`
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

    for n in range(1, 10):
        data = u'Message number {}'.format(n)
        # Data must be a bytestring
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)
        print(future.result())

    print('Published messages.')
    # [END pubsub_quickstart_publisher]
    # [END pubsub_publish]
```

I have subsequently created a raft of modified versions, none of which perform the task I am looking to achieve.  The latest iteration being:

```
import pyodbc
import os
import sys

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "H:\\venv\\SQLBDtoBigQuery\\key.json"

sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM EMP"
connectionString = f"DRIVER={{SQL Server}};server={server};database={database};uid={username};pwd={password}"

conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor = conn.cursor().execute(sqlSelect)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
print(columns)

results = []

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

def publish_messages(project_id, topic_name, inbound_data):
    """Publishes multiple messages to a Pub/Sub topic."""
    # [START pubsub_quickstart_publisher]
    # [START pubsub_publish]
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    # TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
    # TODO topic_name = "Your Pub/Sub topic name"

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    # The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
    # in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}`
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

    for row in inbound_data:        
        # Data must be a bytestring
        str_data=row
        data = str_data.encode('utf-8')
        # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, attribute=data)

    print('Published messages.')
```

I have subsequently developed a method which successfully writes to my pubsub topic, however the records are not being written to the Big Query table. the other problem is that it assumes all database columns were strings when they are in fact a mix of numeric, strings and datetimes. The following is the code I now have.

```
import pyodbc
import os
import sys

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "H:\\venv\\SQLBDtoBigQuery\\key.json"

sqlSelect = "SELECT top 2 EMP_SK FROM EMP"
connectionString = f"DRIVER={{SQL Server}};server={server};database={database};uid={username};pwd={password}"


def GetRowsFromDb(connectionString, sqlSelect):
   ret = []
   columns = []
   with pyodbc.connect(connectionString) as conn:
       with conn.cursor() as cursor:           
           cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
           columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
           ret = list(cursor.fetchall())
   return ret, columns


def publish_messages(project_id, topic_name, inbound_data, columns):
    """Publishes multiple messages to a Pub/Sub topic."""
    # [START pubsub_quickstart_publisher]
    # [START pubsub_publish]
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    # TODO project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
    # TODO topic_name = "Your Pub/Sub topic name"

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    # The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
    # in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}`
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

    namesToValues = dict()
    for row in inbound_data:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            namesToValues[columns[i]] = str(row[i])
        #namesToValues = dict(zip(columns, row))
        # Data must be a bytestring
        str_data="Something"
        data = str_data.encode('utf-8')
        # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data, **namesToValues)

    print('Published messages.')


dbRows, columns = GetRowsFromDb(connectionString, sqlSelect)

publish_messages('lucky-trail-260923', 'aspectdb-0001', dbRows, columns)
```

Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Warm Regards Scott

Comment: I understand your issue here is regarding the publication of SQL Server messages to Pub/Sub. In order to help you I would need more information as I don't really understand where you are stuck. Could you be more precise on what's your problem? Have you been able to publish messages to Pub/Sub? Have you been able to extract information from SQL Server? What is the error message you are facing?

Comment: Also some clarification on why you're using Pub/Sub too. DataFlow can and probably should just be written to do the pulling directly. E.g. when is the script you have here run? On a timer? On some event? Unless you have multiple processes that want to do something to that SQL Server data, Pub/Sub is likely an unnecessary middle step here.

Comment: @Joaquim Gabe thank you for your replies.  To clarify, I can extract the data from SQL Sever without a problem.  My issue is purely around how to use Python to  parse this data to Pubsub in a way that it can accept so that Dataflow can then push the information into BigQuery.  The reason we are using Dataflow is because this is purely a POC of a smaller part of the larger architecture being proposed.  I am just attempting to do so with SQL Server because that is what I have access to at present.

Comment: My latest version of the code doesn't error and successfully writes to pubsub, however Dataflow is unable to write the records to the desired Big Query table.  I have added my latest code to the OP.

Comment: Unfortunately the records aren't being written to the errors table due to a permissions issue, which I am also attempting to overcome, hence I am unable to provide any more information at this time.

Comment: For Dataflow permissions you could take a look here [1], as it is explained how Cloud Dataflow service account works. 
In case you want to grant specific permissions to write to BigQuery, you could also use an user-managed service-account with BigQuery dataEditor role, in addition to the Dataflow required permissions (dataflow.admin or dataflow.developer [2]).




--------------------
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions
[2]: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control